# Is there a way to make every variable inside a definition or class to become global automatically?

Tags: python

I am using a large list of variables inside some definitions and classes (mainly because I want to be able to use the code-folding feature of pydev). Is there any constructor I can use on a definition or class to make its variables automatically considered globals?

---

This is an example of what I did after following some of the recommendations provided on the comments:

From:

```
img_globe       = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_globe.png')
img_help        = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_help.png')
img_exit        = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_exit.png')
img_open        = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_open.png')
img_tutorial    = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_tutorial.png')
img_save        = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_save.png')
img_site        = os.path.join(set_img_dir, 'img_site.png')
```

... (long, long list)

To:

```
varies = {}
dirList=os.listdir(set_img_dir)
for fname in dirList: 
    varies[fname.split(".")[0]] = os.path.join(set_img_dir, fname)
```

Comment: What benefit do you gain from this? This is a terrible idea. If your program requires this, your architecture is fundamentally broken.

Comment: One of the reasons is that I want to know it for the sake of knowing it. The other is that I would like to able to use the code-folding feature that eclipse has (which applies only to classes and definitions). I would like to do it even if it is only a temporary solution to make browsing the code during development easier.

Comment: what do globals have to do with code folding ??

Comment: If you use pydev, you will see that on the moment a variable is inside a class or definition, you can collapse (fold the code) - thus making that section of code disappear. It would be useful for me, at least during development to hide a portion of my variables - paths to images, for example - to make browsing easier.

Comment: So let me paraphrase: You have a ton of global variables, which is bad enough, and now you want to place them somewhere where they'd usually be local variables, but still make them global somehow *just so you can use code folding to hide the whole mess*? Yes, there are a few ways, but I for one won't post any of them - I don't want to contribute to The Daily WTF.

Comment: @relima: So you're saying you want to put some of your module's global variables into a class or function definition so you can hide & show them easily in your IDE but still have them be global -- correct?

Comment: Perhaps you can contribute with suggestions as to how I should handle with the need for so many globals. Dictionaries? Is it always better to have everything inside one dictionary?

Comment: @martineau: yes, this was the original problem. I am going to try to reduce my large number of globals now, though - after reading all of these comments, it seems obvious that I shouldn't be using so many of them.

Comment: It's impossible to tell "now THAT'S the best solution". But in general, very few variables need to be global - instead, they can be made locals and explicitly passed as parameters to the functions that need them; others can be reduced to dictionary entries or object attributes; good OOP can reduce the need for shared state; etc pp. All these have in common that they tend to make the code easier to follow, more modular/reusable, less prone to weird race conditions and name clashes, and cleaner when it grows in size.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you should not do this and the solution you are looking for is not as simple as you might think, here is a very simple example of how you might take the local variables from within a function and make them global:

```
def make_locals_globals():
    """This is just bad"""
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

    locals_dict = locals()
    globals_dict = globals()

    print 'Locals:', locals_dict

    for varname, varval in locals_dict.items():
        print 'Setting global: %s=%s' % (varname, varval)
        globals_dict[varname] = varval

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_locals_globals()

    print '\nGlobals:'
    print 'foo=', foo
    print 'bar=', bar
```

Comment: I thought it was a simple one-liner problem. Besides expecting some drawbacks in efficiency, I was very surprised to learn (from the comments) that this behavior is so heavily discouraged. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason you should not do this is because it enforces bad practice of expecting all variable to be global. Once that happens it becomes hard (if not impossible) to track which operation is referencing what variable, and it is always too easy to overwrite a global in the local scope, unless you are OCD with your variable naming. Python has distinct and elegant scoping rules that work to your benefit if you let them.

Comment: You are right, I have been pretty obsessive with the naming of my variables for this reason. I am going to try to make use of dictionaries.

Comment: @relima: Maybe you should try some other IDEs (although I've heard pydev is one of the best). FWIW the text editor I use most of the time will let me hide any lines I wish (it's also Python syntax-aware).

Comment: You could one-liner it with `globals().update(locals())`.  With great power comes great... gas.

Comment: @jathanism: Good answer, but I doubt that your one-liner in the comments would help him hide and show the variables in his IDE.

Comment: @jathanism: Now that I think more about it, your one-liner at the end of a function assigning to all the variables **would** allow them to hidden & shown as part of the function body in the IDE. I'm not condoning the use of lots of global variables, just trying to determine what's possible.